# How to use a FORMAT as a parameter in a SAS MACRO?

Tags: parameters, macros, format, sas

I'm new on this site, I hope I could have an aswer to my problem.

I'm trying to do a SAS MACRO where I give several parameters. One parameter is a SAS FORMAT and I know if I can do that. And if I can I don't know how to do it.

Here is my SAS MACRO code:

```
%macro creation_graphique_par_classe (listvar=,titre=,format_var=);
goptions reset=global;
PROC GCHART DATA = moyennes_fichier1_clus;
TITLE &titre;
VBAR _NAME_ / DISCRETE
SUBGROUP = _NAME_
SUMVAR = COL1
TYPE = SUM
GROUP = cluster 
coutline=black
woutline=1 ;
LABEL COL1 = "Moyenne en MW" _NAME_ = "Production" Cluster= "Classe";
FORMAT _NAME_ &format_var. cluster classe.; 
WHERE _NAME_ IN &listvar;
RUN ; QUIT ;
%mend;
```

So "format_var" is the parameter I want to give.

Here is the CALL to my macro:

```
%creation_graphique_par_classe (listvar=&list_var_espt,titre='Production en  
Espagne',format_var=$_NAME_nom_complet);
```

It says that it can't find _NAME_NOM_COMPLET in the SAS TABLE WORK.moyennes_fichier1_clus.

Do you know how I could fix it?

Thanks by advance,

Best Regards

Cédric

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a period.  Formats always end in period (or a period then a number for formats with decimal lengths).  So your call needs to be:

```
%creation_graphique_par_classe (listvar=&list_var_espt,titre='Production en  
      Espagne',format_var=$_NAME_nom_complet.);
```

You could also put the period in the format statement, but if you do that you need to do it twice because the first (optional) period terminates the macro variable.

```
format _NAME_ &format_var..;
```

Comment: Tiny nuance: not all formats end with a period. (but they do all contain a period) ;)

Comment: I've already found the solution by myself but thank you for helping me :)

Comment: @user2668031 - well done for finding the solution on your own. You should still accept if you think this is the best response to your question.. (Tick mark on left hand side)

Comment: @user2668031 That, or post the solution you found.  StackOverflow is all about helping other people.